# Remotely change parameters values from the outside (like XCP)

Tags: c, sockets, calibration, parameterization, xcp

I am developing an application in C on an Embededd Linux platform.

I would like to have a way of setting values of variables (i.e.: parameters) from the outside (calibration protocol)

Example of a parameter would be the initial value of a counter keeping track of the uptime of the system. (Additionally, I would need to periodically save the current uptime value, storing it somewhere (e.g.: into a file) and loading the updated initial value when the application is started again.)

I had a brief experience with Embedded C programming of ECU communicating over CAN bus and there I used CCP protocol (XCP protocol over CAN bus) to update values of parameters.

I would like to have something similar to what I had with CCP, but on a more complex system (not just a bare-metal system, but a Linux OS) and by performing parameters update operations remotely (e.g.: with a UDP or TCP socket).

How can I achieve this? Is there some standard protocol to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since XCP stands for "Universal Measurement and Calibration Protocol", you can implement on any communication layer (including ethernet with UDP or TCP socket).

Vector offers a great collection of documentation and examples: [Vector XCP](https://www.vector.com/int/en/know-how/technologies/protocols/xcp-measurement-and-calibration-protocol/?etcc_cmp=Calibration_EN&etcc_grp=XCP&etcc_med=SEA&etcc_par=Google&etcc_bky=xcp&etcc_mty=e&etcc_plc=&etcc_ctv=430490834772&etcc_bde=c&etcc_var=Cj0KCQjwo-aCBhC-ARIsAAkNQisjWIUbEQl5W79TnoSaMYfopSdvQqB2C6FqgHnOSxobIFksoRCy8X4aAnlNEALw_wcB&gclid=Cj0KCQjwo-aCBhC-ARIsAAkNQisjWIUbEQl5W79TnoSaMYfopSdvQqB2C6FqgHnOSxobIFksoRCy8X4aAnlNEALw_wcB#c203723)